# removing file from git history doesn't work

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to remove a file which has sensitive data using [this GitHub procedure](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

However, this doesn't work for my specific repo. When I run:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch some_file.json' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

It completes with:

```
Rewrite 73f9cce9ab282cec272022314f361c1cd48955a7 (418/418)  
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged     
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/blah' is unchanged    
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/blah2' is unchanged     
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/blah3' is unchanged     
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/blah4' is unchanged     
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

But nothing has changed.  When I do

```
git push origin master --force
```

it says

> Everything up-to-date

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Odd. And the file definitely has history? Also I assume `some_file.json` is its complete path?

Comment: Okay yes, i'm lame.  I wasn't using the full path.  I guess that's required. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. As far as git is concerned, the file's name includes its complete path, otherwise there's no difference between `./some_file.json` and `./path/here/some_file.json`.

Answer (score 6):

Per discussion in comments, use the complete path of the file. The current version of the command is excising `some_file.json` in the top level repo directory.