# Preserve --no-ff merge commits with git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter

Tags: git

I have a git repository with the following structure:

```
.git/
    project-root/
        abc/
        xyz/
```

And this is what I want:

```
project-root/
    .git
    abc/
    xyz/
```

I've been researching how to achieve this and this is what I've found so far: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

According to that, I should achieve what I want with the following command:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter project-root -- --all
```

This rewrites the commit history but most of the non-fast-forward merge commits are lost (see image below).

**Is there any way to preserve those commits?**

[image]

Comment: This is a great question: the screenshots are beautiful and really express what's going on.  However, the example repo layout you give is a bit ambiguous since the `project-root` folder has no siblings.  Those siblings would be removed by `subdirectory-filter` but not by the `tree-filter` that you describe in your answer.  Can I suggest that you expand on the example?  In most cases where `subdirectory-filter` is being used, your `project-root` folder would be one among many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using --tree-filter instead of --subdirectory-filter and it seems to work for me. This is the command I've used:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git mv -k project-root/{,.[!.],..?}* .' -- --all
```

After running this command, the commit history is rewritten like if "project-root" had never been tracked by git, and the branch topology is preserved, just how I wanted it.

If someone tries to use this on windows and gets a "permission denied" error, killing the explorer.exe process might help (I found this workaround here: http://academe.co.uk/2011/12/git-mv-permission-denied/).

**Edit:** The command above doesn't rewrite tags. In order to rewrite tags, the right command is:

> git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git mv -k project-root/{,.[!.],..?}*
>   .' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

Comment: This did not work for me.  I keep getting lots of `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/<branchName>' is unchanged`.  I have seen other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240949/how-to-remove-a-file-permanently-in-git-without-getting-warning-ref-refs-head) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149744/removing-file-from-git-history-doesnt-work) where this problem was from incorrect path causing the `git mv ...` command to the tree filter to do nothing.  My path is correct and I can run the `git mv...` command manually and it does in fact cause changes.

Answer (score 2):

As the docs point out [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html):

```
--subdirectory-filter <directory>

    Only look at the history which touches the given subdirectory. The result will 
    contain that directory (and only that) as its project root. Implies 
    [Remap_to_ancestor].
```

I believe the problem is that the merge commits do not actually touch the given subdirectory, meaning that subdirectory-filter doesn't even look at them, and thus can't preserve them.  Thus, we must use another filter which examines each and every commit.  tree-filter is perfect for this, but we must write a script to do what we want done to each commit.

Furthermore, my problem was actually a bit broader than the example, as my `project-root` folder had siblings which I wanted to remove.  The subdirectory filter would remove them, but in order to do so with the tree filter it was helpful for `find` to come to the rescue.

It was convenient to put the commands to be run each time in a separate file.

for a repo structured like this:

```
.git/ 
someDirectory/
someFile.txt
otherDirectory/
dontDeleteThisOne/
project-root/
    xyz/
    abc/
```

This is what worked for me:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter /absolute/path/to/filterScript.sh --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

where /absolute/path/to/filterScript.sh is an executable script containing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#save the folder dontDeleteThisOne so it won't get deleted
git mv -fk dontDeleteThisOne project-root && \
#remove everything not under project-root
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 '(' -name project-root -o -name '.git' ')' -prune -o -exec git rm -rf --ignore-unmatch '{}' ';' && \
#move the contents of the project-root directory up to root
git mv -fk project-root/{,.[!.],..?}* .;
```

the resulting repo structure is then this:

```
.git/
dontDeleteThisOne/
xyz/
abc/
```

This result is equivalent to the result of `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter project-root`, *EXCEPT* that merge commits are preserved in the history, as desired.

Of course, this takes MUCH longer than using the subdirectory filter...

Comment: "I believe the problem is that the merge commits do not actually touch the given subdirectory <...> and thus can't preserve them." This is not factually correct, I have git merges that have been created in a context of exactly this subdirectory, but for some reason end result is flattened for most (but not all) branches.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "created in a context of exactly..."?  What I'm getting at with that statement is that I suspect that a merge commit created because of --no-ff does not actually contain any changes to any files at all, and thus do not contain changes to any files in the directory to be preserved, and are thus filtered out by the subdirectory filter.

Comment: By context I meant that we worked exclusively in a sub-directory. Think of our repo as repository of repositories. Each sub-directory from a root was another project. So our branches, merges, cherry picks and etc were working exclusively on and in that sub-folder. Thus I used word context. And because your statement was suggesting that merge commits disappeared because branch didn't touch mentioned sub-directory. I said it's factually incorrect. Our git merges, 90% of them, disappeared.

Comment: But in general yes, I misinterpreted your sentence. Sorry for that.

Comment: I see what you mean.  What I'm saying is that the 90% of your merge commits that were eliminated contained changes to no files at all (because the merge in question worked with no conflicts) and thus to no files in your "context" subdirectory in particular.

Comment: so im not saying the problem is that the branch didn't touch files in the directory.  I am saying the problem is that the merge commit itself didn't touch any files whatsoever (i think)

Comment: Excellent solution - I added a `$1` parameter to the script (and removed the `dontDeleteThisOne` handling) so I can repeat this more easily in the future.