# How can I remove all instances of a certain filename from a Git repo?

Tags: windows, git, git-rm

I have some files, for example one being `error_log` and some of these may have accidentally been added to git before they were added to the `.gitignore` file so I am wondering how can I delete all instances of *files* with this name from a Git repo?

Note that I want them left on the server so I would be using the `--cached` option.

Comment: It's not clear from your question: do you want to delete the file from the entire commit history or only not to track it in the future? Two different cases, see 2 answers below.

Comment: Sorry, my main issue was just not tracking it in the future. Removing it altogether doesn't matter either way really.

Answer (score 2):

```
find -name "error_log" | xargs git rm --cached
```

Should do the trick

Comment: It affects only the current state of repo, forces not to track "error_log"

Comment: I'm sorry I accidentally tagged this as Linux as my server is linux based but I'm doing this on my dev machine, which is Windows.

Comment: Will work under `git bash`. If "error_log" is in your repo's root folder you can just use `git rm --cached error_log`

Comment: `fatal: pathspec './public_html/error_log' did not match any files`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `filter-branch` to wipe it completely from your commit history (all commits):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter --prune-empty "find . -name error_log | xargs --no-run-if-empty git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch"
```

(Solution 5 [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188613) or [GitHub's remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/))

***Note!*** You will ***loose all you old revisions of "error_log"*** this way! Only the file in its last state would be available. If you want just to exclude file from repo ***not to track it in the future*** use @blue112 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082699)

Comment: I'm sorry I accidentally tagged this as Linux as my server is linux based but I'm doing this on my dev machine, which is Windows.

Not sure if this will work on Windows?

Comment: Will work under [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) that is the default way to use `git` under `windows`

Comment: Not sure if it matters or not, but got the warning: `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged` after running this command.

Comment: It's because your `error_log` is [not under repository root folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12149964). 've changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Got this: `index filter failed: find -name "error_log" | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch`

Comment: You have commits that do not contain that file. So, use `xargs --no-run-if-empty`. Affects `blue112's` answer too. Changed my answer.

Comment: You have only one error_log in certain path, `git filter-branch --index-filter --prune-empty 'git rm --cached relative_path_to_your_file/file'` would be easier. E.g. `git filter-branch --index-filter --prune-empty 'git rm --cached garbage/errors/error_file'`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but now I get: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'find -name "error_log" | xargs --no-run-if-empty git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: It is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21394563 In some shells (and that you're running for your git) `'` does not suite, and one should use double-quote `"`:
`git filter-branch --index-filter --prune-empty "find -name error_log | xargs --no-run-if-empty git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch"` I wonder if this would do the trick at last!))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106755/discussion-between-john-west-and-brett).

Comment: Did you see my message in chat? Sorry, unsure if you get notifications for chat msgs.

Answer (score 0):

> cd *git-project-file*
>
> while read i; do git rm --cached $PWD/$i ; done < .gitignore

then make commits

With this you remove those files from present commits.

If you want to remove from the history, you will have to do more. So, comment below if you need to do it.

---

## Explaination:

You said:

> I have **some files**, for example one being error_log and some of these may have accidentally been **added to git** before they were added to the **.gitignore** file ...

so what the script does is it reads the .gitignore file line by line
so the script runs a while loop where

$i is a line

$PWD is path of present directory

so $PWD/$i is the path of the file/s in each line of .gitignore file.

It run git rm --cached $PWD/$i  for each line in .gitignore.

if the file  $PWD/$i is not  added to git (i.e. if the file in not one of yours error_logs) it does no harm.
if it is one of your error_logs, then it removes the file from cache.

make sure you add files to .gitignore first then run  the script

Comment: How does this reference the `error_log` file and what does `$PWD/$i` do?

Comment: I appended the explanation in the above answer, because the comment's presentation is unformatted and not readable.

Comment: Ahh ok. I guess it's just a bit much through as I know the files I need to delete and the repository is quite large so don't really want to run through and check every file.

Comment: ok then you can you the find command, 
if the files  are more than than three you can write the file names in a temp.txt file
then run 
while read i; do git rm --cached $i ; done < temp.txt